# Django Model Serializers

Tags: python, json, django

I'm learning how to use Django Rest Framework and I came out with a question that I can't get to answer.

I understood that the concept of nested serializer but I think there should be a way to get a specific field in an "upper level" instead of "digging" trough levels. Let me better explain what I mean.

I have `Users` which then are classified into 2 categories `Customers` (which are the default `User` category) and `Drivers`. All the `Users` have a `Profile` with their picture so I would like to obtain the `name` and the `image` in an API. The only solution I've been managing to find is the following

```py
class OrderProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("id", "image")


class OrderUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = OrderProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "profile")


class OrderCustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="get_full_name")
    profile = OrderProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "name", "profile")


class OrderDriverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="user.get_full_name")
    user = OrderUserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = ("id", "name", "user")
```

This is the JSON response

```js
{
    "shipping": {
        "id": 25,
        "customer": {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Test Customer",
            "profile": {
                "id": 10,
                "image": "/media/profile_pics/default.jpg"
            }
        },
        "driver": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Driver",
            "user": {
                "id": 28,
                "profile": {
                    "id": 11,
                    "image": "/media/profile_pics/default.jpg"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can make it to work anyway, but I believe that to learn I should always push for a more "elegant" solution rather than "keep the easiest". So I would like to achieve the following response:

```js
{
    "shipping": {
        "id": 25,
        "customer": {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Test Customer",
            "image": "/media/profile_pics/default.jpg"
        },
        "driver": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Driver",
            "image": "/media/profile_pics/default.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any tips/help/suggest that you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
profile = OrderProfileSerializer()
```

re-write to:

```
   image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   def get_image(self, obj):
        # obj is the customer object
        # return what u need (like this example) or write a model inner method 

        return obj.profile.image
```

This would align nicely to the json you want

Do the same thing for Driver and User